# bash script doesn't work unless bad command given

Tags: linux, bash

I have a [script](https://gist.github.com/kb100/15a18e2ba06a453d0f2c) that doesn't work (it freezes my status line) until it is completely done. However, by adding a random bad command, e.g.

```
asdfasdf
```

anywhere in the file that the script reaches (i.e. not right after an `exit 0` or in a comment), the script works perfectly (does not freeze).

What can cause this kind of behaviour and how do I fix it?

Comment: You cannot receive a useful answer unless you share your code.

Comment: _Xe already has_, glenn jackman.  Follow the hyperlink.

Comment: Linking to the code is not accepted practice on SuperUser.  Links rot; visitors should not have to click through to see what the question is about.

Comment: Your script is long and seems to have some external dependencies which are not completely clear to me.  You are much more likely to receive help if you can reduce your problem to a [minimal, verifiable, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it here in toto.

Comment: A typical symptom of "freezing" in a shell script is that a command is reading standard input, and you aren't typing anything.  Obvious cases like `grep foo` when you meant `grep foo file` are easy to spot; slightly harder cases are `grep foo $file` where the variable `file` is empty can be quite challenging, especially if they do not reproduce always.  (A useful practice for other reasons, too, would be to properly quote `"$file"`; then you get an error message when the argument to `grep` doesn't just completely disappear.)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue can be used by enabling trace output.  This can be done by prefixing the command line with `bash -x`.  In the script you can add `-x` to the bang path.

Once you know where the issue is or likely is you can use the `set` command in the script to turn trace on and off.  `set -x` turns on tracing and `set +x` turns it off.

Comment: While this is good debugging advice, it actually does not appear to address the actual question posted by the OP.